# Solving the integral for box of radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integration

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cU7bj4dNMwY&t=3914s

Susskind lecture 7 on statistical mechanics show how to calculate energy for box of radiation. After model description and some passages (at 1:03) we arrive to the following integral,

$$\frac{L^3}{\pi^3c^3h^3\beta^4}\int_{0}^{\infty }d^3u \frac{u}{e^u-1}.$$

the next move of lecture (1:04) is a kind of passage to a line integral using spherical coordinates which I cannot understand:

$$\frac{L^3}{\pi^3c^3h^3\beta^4}\frac{1}8{}\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{4\pi u^3}{e^u-1}du.$$

I add $du$ that do not compare on lecture.

Then it continue with solving the line integral. It seems something standard to be managed with some approximation. However, I haven't focused on it yet but have seen many explanations on the web that address it. The point that most worries and blocks me is this triple integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, we can write $\vec{u} = u(\sin\theta\cos \phi , \sin\theta \sin\phi , \cos\theta)$. The measure is then
$$
d^3 u = u^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi du 
$$
The $u$ in your first integral should really be $|\vec{u}|$ (it is standard notation to denote the norm of a vector $\vec{u}$ simply by $u$). Then your first integral is
$$
\int d^3 u \frac{|\vec{u}|}{e^{|\vec{u}|} - 1 } = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \int_0^\infty \frac{u^3}{e^u-1} .
$$
The integration region for $\theta$ and $\phi$ is $(0,\pi/2)$ because we are integrating over only one octant of the sphere (*I assume this is true because of the factor of $\frac{1}{8}$ you have in your second integral. Since you have not provided the link to the lectures, I cannot verify this for myself!!*).
Then,
$$
\int d^3 u \frac{|\vec{u}|}{e^{|\vec{u}|} - 1 } = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{u^3}{e^u-1} = \frac{1}{8} \int_0^\infty \frac{4\pi u^3}{e^u-1}  .
$$

EDIT - I just watched the referenced lecture and he is indeed integrating over the only one octant.

Comment: Why 4 π, from where?

Comment: uhhhh... $\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{1}{8} \times 4\pi$.

Comment: i was thinking 1/8 is because integrating for one octant that means divide the integral by 8. The  π/2 was already the result from the second integral so $\frac{\pi }{2}\frac{1}{8}\int ...$

Comment: The integration over one octant is reflected in the integration ranges for $\theta$ and $\phi$. If you integrate over the entire sphere then the ranges are $\theta \in ( 0 , \pi )$ and $\phi \in (0 , 2\pi )$. You could also integrate over this entire range and then multiply by $\frac{1}{8}$. It'll give you the same answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your time.